# new array list created everytime function is called recursively

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist

I'm converting a string to a Character ArrayList recursively. A new ArrayList is created everytime the function is called.

```
public static ArrayList<Character> strToList(String word)
{
    ArrayList<Character> letters = new ArrayList<Character>();
    //ArrayList<Character> emptyList = new ArrayList<Character>();
    if(word.isEmpty() == true){
        return letters;        
    }
    else {
        char let = word.charAt(0);
        letters.add(Character.valueOf(let));
        System.out.println(letters);
        String temp = word.substring(1, word.length());
        System.out.println(temp);
        return strToList(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you think static is the culprit :) ?

Comment: What is your question? Please [Edit] your post.

Comment: yes, because everytime this `ArrayList<Character> letters = new ArrayList<Character>();` is getting called

Comment: Define ArrayList as static .

Comment: Yes, that is what your code says: create a new list. But what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Either pass a single `ArrayList` instance as an argument to your method (`public static void strToList(String word, List<Character> letters)` - your method doesn't have to return anything in this case), or merge the `ArrayList` instances as follows:

```
public static ArrayList<Character> strToList(String word)
{
    ArrayList<Character> letters = new ArrayList<Character>();
    if (!word.isEmpty()) {
        char let = word.charAt(0);
        letters.add(Character.valueOf(let));
        System.out.println(letters);
        String temp = word.substring(1, word.length());
        System.out.println(temp); 
        letters.addAll(strToList(temp)); // add all the elements of the List returned by the
                                         // recursive call to the new List created in this 
                                         // call
    }
    return letters;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating your code as below

```
    public static ArrayList<Character> strToList(String word, ArrayList<Character> letters)
    {
//        ArrayList<Character> letters = new ArrayList<Character>();
        //ArrayList<Character> emptyList = new ArrayList<Character>();
        if(word.isEmpty() == true){
            return letters;
        }
        else {
            char let = word.charAt(0);
            letters.add(Character.valueOf(let));
            System.out.println(letters);
            String temp = word.substring(1, word.length());
            System.out.println(temp);
            return strToList(temp, letters);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ArrayList<Character> letters = new ArrayList<Character>();
        System.out.println(strToList("Hello", letters)); // [H, e, l, l, o]

}
```

In recursion, you need to be careful regarding the variable's scope.
In your post, since you are creating new ArrayList on each call stack, it does not have data from the previous call stack.
So to pass around list data I am passing it as an argument to the function. This will retain all data from all the call stacks.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to avoid changing the parameters of the function.

Comment: Then this is best suitable answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56124086/2987755, I did not want to change logic of your function, so added this version as answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also do that in this way

```
public static ArrayList<Character> strToCharList(String word) {
    ArrayList<Character> letters = new ArrayList<Character>();
    if (word.isEmpty() == true) 
        return letters;
     else 
        return (ArrayList<Character>) word.chars().mapToObj(character -> (char) character).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Or

```
public static ArrayList<Character> strToCharList(String word) {
    return (word != null)? (ArrayList<Character>) word.chars().mapToObj(character -> (char) character).collect(Collectors.toList()): new ArrayList<Character>();
}
```

Method call

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(strToList("Hello"));
}
```

Output:

```
[H, e, l, l, o]
```